# C# create textBox name on the fly

Tags: c#, textbox

I'm trying to create a textBox name on the fly as I have a lot of them so it will make it easier to write to them and not use a loop. I'm using Visual Stdio 2010, .NET 2.0. The code below is my example but I can't get it to work.

```
private delegate void NameCallBack(string varText, int b);
public void UpdateTextBox(string input, int t)
{
    //TextBox tb = FindControl ("textBox" + t.ToString()) as TextBox;
    TextBox tb = this.Controls["textBox" + t.ToString()] as TextBox;

    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        tb.BeginInvoke(new NameCallBack(UpdateTextBox), new object[] { input, t });  
    }
    else
    {
        tb.Text = tb.Text + Environment.NewLine + input;
    }
}
```

I have had a look at a few examples on here and other sources from the net but I just don't understand. Could someone point out what might be a stupid mistake please? Many thanks :)

Sorry the error I get is that it does not update the textBox, which is not really an error. If I use the code that is commented out then it can't find the "FindControl" method. I have looked as this.controls but I'm so confused I have been trying this for ages, I think I need a break :)

Comment: What is not working? What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Look at the Controls.Find() method.

Comment: Sorry the error I get is that it does not update the textBox, which is not really an error. If I use the code that is commented out then it can't find the "FindControl" method. I have looked as this.controls but I'm so confused I have been trying this for ages, I think I need a break :)

Comment: FindControl is a System.Web.UI method. Are you using winforms or developing a web page?

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code to a sample WinForms project and it works correctly.

You've probably already checked this, but it's worth mentioning that you want your `TextBox` to be `Multiline` and you add a line break **before** adding the actual text, so the first line is empty. 
**If your `TextBox`'s height allows it to show only one line at a time, the line with text may just not be visible**, so it seems like it's not updated.

Either way, I've made some minor modifications to your code in order to simplify it a little bit and not to enter a new line before first input:

```
private delegate void NameCallBack(string varText, int b);
public void UpdateTextBox(string input, int t)
{
    TextBox tb = this.Controls[String.Format("textBox{0}", t)] as TextBox;

    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        tb.BeginInvoke(new NameCallBack(UpdateTextBox), input, t);
    }
    else
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
        {
            tb.Text += Environment.NewLine;
        }
        tb.Text += input;
    }
}
```

It seems to work.

**Update**

If this still does not work, the issue seems to be somewhere else. 
Please check again it the text box you want the text to appear in to be named `textBox<x>`, where `<x>` is the appropriate number.

Another thing is to make sure any exceptions are not thrown (they may be caught somewhere else in your code). To break at all exceptions go to ***Debug***, ***Exceptions...*** and in the window that appears check the checkbox in *Thrown* column associated with *Common Language Runtime Exceptions*.

Comment: Hey thanks for this! The only thing is my text box is about 600 x 600, multi line but does not show anything, but if I comment out the Textbox tb = ... and assign tb to textBox2 it displays correctly on the screen, any ideas?

Comment: How do you call the UpdateTextBox method? Make sure you use something like UpdateTextBox("my text", 2);.

Comment: I call it using... Program.MainLogWindow.UpdateTextBox(convertedHex, textBox);

Comment: If possible, attach a debugger and put a breakpoint there and just make sure that convertedHex is not empty and textBox euqals to an appropriate number. If it doesn't help, paste a code that shows where the values come from, so we'll try to work this out :).

Comment: Hey sorry for the slow reply, I appreciate the help! The code that sends the ASCII to but output to the textBox is this

        public void hexToAscii(String hex, int textBox)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i += 2)
            {
                string hs = hex.Substring(i, 2);
                sb.Append(Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToUInt32(hs, 16)));
            }
            string convertedHex = sb.ToString();
            Program.MainLogWindow.UpdateTextBox(convertedHex, textBox);
        }

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint there to see the values of parameters in the line Program.MainLogWindow.UpdateTextBox(convertedHex, textBox);?

Comment: Yea, the values are correct, I can print them out just above where it's meant to write to the screen and they are correct. :/ thanks for the help!

Comment: Try to add tb.Invalidate(true); after the line tb.Text += input;. If it won't help, let me know.

Comment: Hey, sorry to be a pain, that hasn't worked either? I really can not for the life of me work it out!

Comment: Please check again it the text box you want the text to appear in to be named textBox<x>, where <x> is the appropriate number. Another thing is to make sure any exceptions are not thrown (they may be caught somewhere else in your code). To break at all exceptions go to Debug, Exceptions... and check appropriate checkboxes in Thrown column. The last thing, just to make sure: you are writing a WinForms or ASP.NET webpage?

Comment: Hey, the text boxes are named correct, no exceptions are thrown, I have caught some, double checked that though. No this is a .NET desktop app :/

Comment: Ok, so put a breakpoint on line:  tb.Text += input;
 and check if it's being hit. Another thing is that there may also be some issues when you use a textbox with some binding.